# Python - "ImportError: cannot import name" for modules in the same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two python files in the same directory. I have also `__init__.py` file as well. Python version is: `3.9.7`

Can't figure out why I can't import the modules.

`a.py`

```
def aaa():
    print ("test")
```

`b.py`

```
from a import aaa

aaa()
```

Error:

```
from a import aaa
ImportError: cannot import name 'aaa' from 'a' (/usr/lib64/python3.9/a.py)
```

Also it doesn't work:

```
from .a import aaa

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Running it as:
`python b.py`
I have tried other options but without success.

**Update: The same simple code `from a import aaa aaa()`
without init.py works on python 2.7.**

```
OS: 
"Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.5"
```

Thanks!

Comment: The directory containing `a.py` and `b.py`, it's not `/usr/lib64/python3.9/`, right?

Comment: Correct! Those two are in some manually created folder

Comment: Are you running `b.py` itself? Or is `b.py` imported by something else that you're running?

Comment: @Samathingamajig running it as `python b.py`

Comment: @Jasmijn can you please assist what I should do since those are outside `/usr/lib64/python3.9/`

Comment: What operating system? (if Linux, which distro)

Comment: @Samathingamajig "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.5"

Comment: If you remove the `__init__.py` file (move it somewhere to keep it saved), what happens (with and without the extra `.`)? Also what is the content of the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: @Samathingamajig I have removed it as it is empty. As I can see the same errors:
`.` ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
`without .` ImportError: cannot import name 'aaa' from 'a' (/usr/lib64/python3.9/a.py)

Comment: What command are you using to run the python file?

Comment: @Samathingamajig `python b.py` 
Is it possible that this is so complicated?

Comment: @AndreyS if you do `python --version`, what comes up? Usually from what I've seen, `python` itself is python 2.x, and `python3` is python 3.x.

Comment: `python --version
Python 3.9.7`

Comment: Can anyone reproduce this? I cannot on my computer with Ubuntu in WSL2

Comment: This works on python version 2.7. simple `from a import aaa
aaa()` without `__init__.py` as well. I will update this in question as well

Comment: @Samathingamajig on different server also with RHEL 8.5 but with python 2.7 this works!

Comment: Can you run python in verbose mode and pastebin the output somewhere? Basically `python -v b.py`.

Comment: Can you print and show us `sys.path`? The error says that it found the "a" module in one of the paths that python uses to hold importable modules (/usr/lib64/python3.9/a.py). That's not one of the standard modules so it would be interesting to see where it came from. `import a;print(dir(a))` would be very interesting. Since python normally adds the script directory to the front of its `sys.path`, it also tells us that you don't have a.py and b.py in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

For relative imports in the same folder, use a single `.`

```py
from .a import aaa
```

Comment: it doesn't work either  :(
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Answer (score 0):

Like Samathingamajig pointed out, you need relative imports.

So, first, change the line in `b.py` to:

```
from .a import aaa
```

You also need to deal with the fact that you now have a package instead of a single module. And Python needs to know how to find your modules.

One way tot deal with that, is to run it using `-m`. If your Python files are in `/some/dir/myproject/`, run it as follows:

```bash
cd /some/dir
python3 -m myproject.b
```

Note the namespace dot replacing the directory separator in that last command.

Alternatively, install your package (I recommend learning about packaging but for now you can simply move the `myproject` directory into one of the directories in `sys.path`), and then you could have any Python file `import myproject.b` or run `python3 -m myproject.b` from any directory.

If you want to have a package that can be used both as a library and a stand-alone application, you could add a `__main__.py` file with the code to run it as an application. That way `python3 -m myproject` would run your main project

Comment: `__main__.py`  should be added to which file? `b.py`?  or both?

Comment: `__main__.py` is its own file @AndreyS

Comment: should I keep `__init.py` in the folder?

Comment: It seems like same error

 `python -m test3.efg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/jenkins/test3/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from a import aaa
ImportError: cannot import name 'aaa' from 'a' (/usr/lib64/python3.9/a.py)`

Comment: I have returned empty `__init__.py` in my dir `test3` but can't run `python -m test3.b` either

Comment: Top level scripts like `python3 b.py` are not in any package and relative imports won't work.

Comment: @AndreyS You do need to have relative imports (`from .a import aaa`) inside the package. I'll add it to my answer. My apologies, I thought it was clear from the first sentence.